# Access violation when attempting to read and write a string?

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm very new to c++. I come from the land of java, so the input/output system is confusing me a bit, so sorry if this is a dumb question.

I'm attempting to declare a string, save some console input to it, and then print the string.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    char* pizza = "";
    std::cin >> pizza;
    std::cout << pizza;


    return 0;
}
```

I get an access violation exception, which makes me think I have an invalid memory address somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll explain what's wrong with your code, but first, the correct code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string pizza;
    std::cin >> pizza;
    std::cout << pizza;

    return 0;
}
```

That uses the standard library string class, instead of a `char*`. Now on to your code.

```
char* pizza = "";
```

This is wrong. It compiles in older standards, but it was still a bad idea even then. String literals, like `""`, are arrays of const chars. With the above line, you are assigning a non-const pointer to this array of const chars. In all other contexts involving arrays and pointers, this is illegal, as it should be. It is allowed (until C++11) for string literals for historical reasons, but you still shouldn't do it. Because even though you have a non-const pointer, it is still illegal to write to the location it points to, which is why you get an access violation when you try to do this:

```
std::cin >> pizza;
```

Comment: Why can't I use a char*?

Comment: @user3238865: You can, you just have to know how to use it properly. i.e. You need to allocate memory properly and point the `char*` to this memory. And you need to be careful not to overflow the memory you've allocated, and a whole host of other problems. But other than getting experience in programming in the language, you'd be wasting your time, because all these problems have already been solved, and the solutions are encapsulated in the `std::string` class, which has been extensively tested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the array some space. Like:

```
char pizza[50];
```

This is going to work, however this code could be writing past the bounds of the array (and for the C++ standard this is just undefined behaviour). As other posters noted, using `std::string` would be more wise and easy to use.

You can check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_basic_input_output.htm) tutorial for quick intro to basic C++ Input/Output.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I suspected that was the problem and tried to do something like `char* pizza = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"` but that didn't work. Is there any reason that you have to give it space in that way?

Comment: @user3238865 The main problem here is that you are coming from Java land where you doesnt manage memory. For quick intro to C++ you can first read a [Java To C++ Tutorial](https://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1230/docs/java_to_cpp.shtml)

Comment: No, the main problem is that he's learning C++ from a terrible source. With proper C++, you don't have to manage memory either. Manual memory management in C++ is a right, not a mandate.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Totally agree. But if he doesn't know what a pointer is, jumping directly from java to C++ is going to be terrible.